# Popview scrolling separately in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have implementing a AutoComplete control in Xamarin.iOS which consisting of one textfield and one popupview to show suggestions based on the search. The controls works well in a normal UIView when it is placed inside a UIScrollview my search filed and suggestion view scrolls separately.(Search filed scrolls and suggestion view stays on the same position). I have adding list of suggestion to UIView and adding them in UIWindow to act like a popup. But unfortunately it did not works in scroll view.

I have tried adding a reference view top of all(search filed and suggestion view) and tried to pass the touch to scrollview and control but unable to pass the touch. The control only takes the touch.

Could any one suggest me how to pass the touch from the reference view to control and scrollview or is there any other way to scroll the suggestion along with the search filed.

Here I have attached the demo sample of my project run the sample and focus the search field. Now the popup will be shown and now try to scroll the screen.

Sample Link: https://ufile.io/4rfnj

Comment: I see the pop view is added to the Window,  why don't you add it to the scrollview?

Comment: Actually i am creating a UIComponent which act likes a AutoComplete control. Consisting of Dropdown and search field. Creating a instance of my  class will show you a textbox in output and it will show suggestions in the popup based on the text which you entered.